# How does mouse movementX work on drag events?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, drag

I am trying to set up dynamic draggable element which will move its anchor point according to the drag delta. However I cannot seem to get the delta using `event.movementX` or `event.movementY`.

My simple drag event code:

```
mainMenuDiv.addEventListener("drag", (event)=>{
   console.log(event.movementX, event.movementY);
});

// The console print out is simply:
//>0 0
// This prints out a lot of times as i drag the mouse but doesn't change the properties.
```

I think i am missing something about the way the `movement` property works with `drag` events.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't get it to work either, so I just did the following:

```
var start = null, delta = null

el.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
    start = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY}
})

el.addEventListener('drag', e => {
    delta = {x: e.clientX - start.x, y: e.clientY - start.y}
})

el.addEventListener('dragend', e => start = delta = null)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `e.nativeEvent.offsetX` and `e.nativeEvent.offsetY`, too.

I don't know the browser support though.